What would cause 'client_secret' error in custom policy technical profile IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims?
Azure AD B2C. Following the invite-via-email example: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite-via-email/source-code/run.csx
We've created and uploaded the various xml files. Generating the token appears to work well, but on redeem we get the following error (traced to Application Insights):

Exception Message:The key with id 'client_secret' not found for technical profile: 'IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims', tenant: 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com', policy: 'B2C_1A_INVITEREDEEM', Exception Type:PolicyException, CorrelationID:xxx

We've tried adding a client_secret value to the IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims technical profile, as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint#step-3-add-the-id-token-hint-technical-profile - but this just results in an unfathomable internal error.
Our technical profile, which throws the above error, looks like this:
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self Referenced ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
      <DisplayName>Self referenced ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="None" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_INVITEREDEEM/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- claims to read from the id_token_hint-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

What are we missing?

I can answer this myself now. As the original error implied, we were simply missing a cryptographic key for the redeem technical profile.
This addition fixes it:
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>

In trying to fix this, we had reference the wrong StorageReferenceId and what makes debugging difficult is that this incorrect reference produces only a generic HTTP.500 error, with no indication of the actual problem.
In addition the example code for the invite/redeem pathway (shown above) has no CryptographicKeys element, so it's not clear one is required.
